# CSS Box-shadow effect when user tapped/ touched div

Tags: html, css

I want to set a box-shadow effect for the particular div in my page when it tapped / touched. How to do it?

I have already tried to create a class with block shadow and assign it into the div with `.className:active`  event. It is working little bit. But the problem is when user is touching and dragging that div, the box-shadow effect is not cancelled.

Comment: "when user is touching and dragging that div, the box-shadow effect is not cancelled." - what is your browser?

Comment: Android webview

Comment: try my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **"cancel"** the dragging by `:active:focus`.

---

Its mean that your div get the `box-shadow` property only on `:active` and the cursor must be `focus`.

**exemple:**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
}

div:active:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px gray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  shadow
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ico-btn {
    -webkit-user-select: none; margin-right: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 1px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.247059) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px -1px 0px 0px inset;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
    border-top-left-radius: 25%;
    border-top-right-radius: 25%;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 2px 10px 0px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 0px 0px 1px 0px, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.247059) 0px 1px 0px 0px inset, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902) 0px -1px 0px 0px inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 140px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 177px; /*167px;*/
    line-height: 150px;
    min-width: 0px;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0; /*30*/
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 220px;/*200*/
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#fff;
}

.ico-btn.red { background-color: rgb(219, 68, 55);
    border-bottom-color:#ab2318;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25%;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-left-style: none;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-right-style: none;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    border-top-color:#ef675c;
    border-top-left-radius: 25%;
    border-top-right-radius: 25%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 2px;
    transition: all .1s linear;
}
.ico-btn.red:hover {
 background-color: #D05944;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
 transition: background-color .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btn red"><span class="icon-sad"></span>
</div>
```

Maybe you want something like htis link:-[CSS Transition hover effect for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228098/css-transition-hover-effect-for-touch-devices)